# Sorting Alphanumeric data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an alphanumeric data like:

```
1
1a
1b
2
2b
10
10a
```

If I sort this data, output will be like:

```
1
1a
10
10a
2
2b
```

But I want output as:

```
1
1a
2
2b
10
10a
```

How to get this output with Oracle command?

Answer (score 10):

So, as I understand, you want to sort by numeric part of your data. For this purpose you can use regular expression (to extract the numeric part) like this:

```
SQL> select str from
  2  (
  3  select '1' str from dual union all
  4  select '1a'  from dual union all
  5  select '1b'  from dual union all
  6  select '2' from dual union all
  7  select '2b'  from dual union all
  8  select '10'  from dual union all
  9  select '10a' from dual
 10  ) t
 11  order by to_number(regexp_substr(str, '^[[:digit:]]*')), str
 12  /

STR
---
1
1a
1b
2
2b
10
10a
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the same by separating number and alphanumeric sorting order in order by clause. check below example:

```
SELECT tt.qdef_grid
       FROM qgdm_qdef tt 
       ORDER BY to_number(substr(tt.qdef_grid,2,2)), substr(tt.qdef_grid,1,1);
```