# how to use order by in alphanumeric column in oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by

In my table one of column i have a value like below

```
Y-1
Y-2
Y-3
Y-4
Y-5
Y-6
Y-7
Y-8
Y-9
Y-10
Y-11
Y-12
Y-13
Y-14
```

when i am order by this column its working fine if the row has value up to Y-9 other wise my result is wrong like below.

```
Y-1
Y-10
Y-11
Y-12
Y-13
Y-14
Y-2
Y-3
Y-4
Y-5
Y-6
Y-7
Y-8
Y-9
```

But i want the output like below

```
Y-1
Y-2
Y-3
Y-4
Y-5
Y-6
Y-7
Y-8
Y-9
Y-10
Y-11
Y-12
Y-13
Y-14
```

How to acheive the above result.i am using oracle database.Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting Alphanumeric data in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469110/sorting-alphanumeric-data-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an order by manipulatinng the column content and cast to number eg:

```
 order by substr(col1, 1,2), TO_NUMBER(sustr(col1, 3,10))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data is in a table `t` with a column `col` and the structure is an alphabetical string followed by dash followed by a number, and both the alphabetical and the number are always not NULL, then:

```
select col from t
order by substr(col, 1, instr(col, '-')), to_number(substr(col, instr(col, '-')+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the good way is to get constant length field

```
select col from t
order by substr(col, 1, 2)|| lpad(substr(col, 3),5,'0')
```

it will correct work only with two nondigit simbol in begining of string up to 99999 number